# Coloqué la barra pero no veo el botón de la scroll bar en java

Tags: java

tengo un problema, coloqué una JScroll bar al costado de mi programa. lo pude hacer con éxito, *sin embargo no se vé para nada el botón cuadrado que sube y baja*, osea que no puedo ver qué hay abajo, queda fijo no baja porque no se vé el botón, sí la barra con las flechas arriba y abajo. me sería de mucha ayuda si me dan una mano, el código está lo mas limpio posible, cuenta de 3 botones, un título, un area de texto sin posibilidad de editar y y una barra de scroll.
gracias

```
package Vista;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.ScrollPane;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class Ventana_libreria extends JFrame  {

    public JPanel panelsuperior, panelcentral, panelinferior;
    public JButton botonatras, botonadelante, botonsalir;
    public JTextArea textarealibreria;
    public JLabel titulo;
    public JScrollPane scroll;



    public Ventana_libreria()
    {


        panelsuperior= new JPanel();
        panelcentral= new JPanel();
        panelinferior= new JPanel();
            textarealibreria= new JTextArea(33,50);
                botonatras= new JButton(new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/flechaverdeatras.png"));
                botonadelante= new JButton(new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/flechaverde.png"));
                botonsalir= new JButton(new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/eject.png"));
                    titulo= new JLabel();
                    scroll= new JScrollPane(textarealibreria);  // Acá creo el scroll
                    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);   //acá lo declaro sólo vertical

                    this.setTitle("Librería de ayuda y orientación");

                    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                        this.add(panelsuperior, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                        panelsuperior.add(titulo);
                        titulo.setText("Datos a tener en cuenta:");

                        this.add(panelcentral, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        panelcentral.add(textarealibreria);     // Acá adhiero el JTextArea al centro
                        this.add(scroll, BorderLayout.EAST);// Acá lo adhiero al lado oeste del borderlayout


                        textarealibreria.setEditable(false);

                        this.add(panelinferior, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                        panelinferior.add(botonatras);
                        panelinferior.add(botonadelante);
                        panelinferior.add(botonsalir);


                        textarealibreria.setText("Area de soporte, debés tener en cuenta que: \n\n• Como todas las cosas existentes los aviones tienen peso y está ligados a las fuerza de gravedad.\n• Este avión tiene un alcance máximo de 1000 km sin repostar en el aire. \n• Su capacidad de carga entre combustible y armamento nunca puede ser mayor a 3000 kg\n• No es efectivo en los duelos a corta distancia.\n• Carga como máx 6 misiles de media corta distancia AMRAAM.\n• Su techo máximo de vuelo son 30000 feet o 99900 metros.\n• Su tren de aterrizaje es extremadamente sensible al vient y/o golpes.\n• Su maniobrabilidad es buena pero su rango de giro nunca es mayor a 65 grados superando los 350 km/h.\n• Cuenta con medidas electromagnéticas o E.C.M , junto con Chaff y Flares o bengalas.\n• El ECM hoy en día es casi obsoleto, no sirve para missiles modernos a menos que esté a menos de 100 m del objetivo.\n• El rango de efectividad de éxito de un AMRAAM a x<100km y x>=1km es del 99%.\n• El rango de efectividad de un Sidewinder moderno es de x<10km y x>=500m es del 99%.\n• Apartir de los 30000 feet pierde sustentabilidad por la liviandad del aire y/o se congelan sus partes.\n• En algunos casos con la turbina apagada y dependiendo del angulo de caída puede planear largas distancias.\n• La cuenta correspondiente al recorrido planeando es= distancia_recorrida*segundos_hasta_la_pista. depende del grado.\n• Para refueling envuelo se necesitan almenos 300 litros de combustible con un consumo menor a 20litros/seg.\n• Los dos modelos más conocidos son el F-16C y F-16B ,el B con una maniobrabilidad 10º menor al C por la plaza extra.\n• Es absolutamente inefectivo ante operaciones contra buques o cruceros.\n• Es altamente reflectivo ante las ondas del radar y el vuelo bajo no sirve a menos que los radares tengan ángulo de 60º.\n• Apesar de su popularidad y su bajo costo, no a todas las naciones les conviene esta unidad por su poca autonomía.\n• Su competidor directo desde el lado URSS es el mig 29, superándolo sólo en tecnología pero con menos maniobravilidad.\n• Los Sidewinder son guiado por calor a muy corta o corta distancia.\n• Los AMRAAM son guiados por radar a corta-media-larga distancia.\n• El AIM-7 Sparrow es un missil de los años 70, hoy en día se evaden hasta con confeti.\n• El AIM-54 Phoenix sólo lo carga el F-14 por su peso, y es 100% efectivo sólo a distancias mayores a 200km.\n• Para que la turbina encienda por la chispa debe pasar por un tiempo de calentanmiento aprox de 5 a 10 min.\n• El corte del sistema de EPU retorna en el corte anexo del la chispa y el combustible.\n• El alcance máximo de su radar nunca supera los 320 km, ganando claridad mientras se baja la distancia análisis.\n• Su sistema de armas no funciona sin radar.\n• No está diseñados para aterrizar en portaviones ni distancias de pista menores a 3 km.\n- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \n• Este sofware fue diseñado por Axel Berlot, sin Netbeans ni otro gestor gráfico, sólo código puro en Eclipse IDE.");




    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es sencillo, estás añadiendo primero el `TextArea` al JFrame en el `CENTER` y luego el `JScrollPane` que también contiene el TextArea (recuerda que se construye a partir de él) en el lado `EAST`.

Basta con poner el `JScrollPane` en el lugar donde quieres el `TextArea`

```java
this.add(panelcentral, BorderLayout.CENTER);
// Comenta esta línea
// panelcentral.add(textarealibreria);
// Cambia la posición del JScrollPane de EAST a CENTER   
this.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
// Incluye un tamaño de pantalla a partir del cual quieres que aparezca el scroll
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 110));
```

Comment: PD: Según esta [guía](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) lo que no te aparecía se llama `knob` y según [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=knob) significa 'pomo' o 'verga'.  ;)

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer, desaparece el JTextArea, osea queda en gris y el scroll sigue igual. es raro

Comment: Tienes que quitar la línea donde añades el TextArea al JFrame y sólo añadir en JScrollPane en donde querías poner el TextArea (en CENTER),

Comment: La verdad, acabó de funcionar, pero no entiendo como, funciona,osea que el JTextarea se adhiere al panel mediante el JScrollPane antes de adehrirse al JFrame? muchas gracias

Comment: El JScrollPane se crea a partir del JTextArea: new JScrollPane(new JTextArea());, o sea en cierto modo uno se adhiere al otro, y el scroll al final es el que se añade al contenido del componente padre. En el doc de Oracle no explican cómo es, pero sería analizar la clase java.swing.JScrollPane.

Comment: La verdad muchas gracias, porque enserio fui a la los docs oficiales de oracle y no encontré esa explicación. gracias ya iban 2 días sin solución. abrazos

Comment: Me alegra oírlo, saludos.